# Can 2-way SSL be tested against browsers(as clients)?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am trying to establish a 2-way SSL connection between an nginx server and a client(browser/postman).
I am wondering whether it should be possible to tell nginx to trust the browser/postman's keys, assuming nginx requests and verifies client's certificates.
specifically, what should be put in that section of nginx

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/newcert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/newkey.pem;


    ssl_session_timeout 15m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;

    # what should be the content of that file??
   >>>>>> ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/trust/client.crt;


}
```

I failed to find any information regarding this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssl_client_certificate` directive points to a file containing the *Certificate Authority* used to sign the client's *Certificate Request*. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate) for details.

If you are using a **self-signed certificate authority** for your client certificates, the procedure would be something like this:

1. Create a self-signed certificate to use as a Certificate Authority. See [OpenSSL CA(1)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ca.html) for a simplified scheme to manage this step.
2. Generate a certificate request for the client. For example:

   ```
   openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout user.key -out user.req
   ```
3. Use the CA from step 1 to sign the request from step 2 to generate a certificate for the client. See OpenSSL CA(1) above.
4. Convert the certificate from step 3 into a PKCS#12 formatted file so that it can be imported by the client. For example:

   ```
   cat user.key user.crt | openssl pkcs12 -export -out user.p12
   ```

Comment: my client is Chrome. I assumed it had it own client-certificates . I have managed to install my server-self-signed certificate on chrome, but this was only 1 way ssl. Maybe I missed something in your answer - Can I generate a client-certificate for chrome? How do I make sure that it uses this certificate when authenticating? my nginx will tell it to use it somehow?